# CSS hover in a nav bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors, hover

I have tried to make a nav bar using the ul li and disabling the text formatting in CSS. The code works almost fine, as I have made also a small fade-in animation for the buttons. The problem appears if I have a dropdown menu in my nav bar. Hovering my mouse over the li which has dropdown in it also causes the things in the dropdown to be animated.

I know there may be some selectors you can use to make it not do so, but so far I haven't got it to work. What would be the right thing to do?

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>

        <a href="index.html"><li id="left">Home</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Menu 1</li></a>

        <li><span>Dropdown</span>
            <ul>
                <a href="#"><li>Dropdown menu 1</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Dropdown menu 2</li></a>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <a href="#"><li>Menu 3</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li id="right">Contact me</li></a>

    </ul>

</nav>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
nav{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  background-color: #d48041;
  box-shadow: 0 1vh 2vh -0.5vh #F2B57B inset;
  width:90%;
  padding-left:10%;
  height:5%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display: inline;
}

nav ul a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.5vh;
}

nav ul a li{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5vh;
  line-height: 5vh;
  width:10%;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul li ul{
  display:none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 91%;
  margin-left: -0.1vw;
}

nav ul li ul li{
  background-color: #FFA968;
  border: solid 0.04vw black;
}

nav ul a li:not(.noborder), nav ul li {
  border-right: solid 0.04vw black;
}

#left {
  border-left: solid 0.04vw black;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right:11.1%;
  border-left: solid 0.04vw black;
}

nav ul a:hover{
  animation-name: text_fadein;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

nav ul li:hover span{
  cursor: default;
}

nav ul a:hover li{
  animation-name: menu_fadein;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting a code snippet of the working code?

Comment: Other buttons should work just fine. Just the Dropdown menu 1 and 2 are also lighted when I have however over Dropdown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent animation getting applied to children use `>` selector to select the immediate child.

```
nav ul>a:hover{
  animation-name: text_fadein;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

nav ul>li:hover span{
  cursor: default;
}

nav ul>a:hover>li{
  animation-name: menu_fadein;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Well it almost seems to work how I wanted it to, but this only makes the "Dropdown" part not animated, but the dropdown menu 1 and 2 are still animated.

Comment: Hi, can you try this? 'nav>ul>a:hover'. The above 'ul' structure is not correct. The 'ul li' structure should be like: '<ul><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>'.

Comment: It would work now, but now the issue comes that the button can only be clicked from the text, not from the 'li' area.

Comment: Adding a `display:block` and `padding` to `a` tag, assuming the structure should be `ul>li>a`.